# Setting ID input (DOM) issue

Tags: javascript

I wonder why this won't work. I'm trying to set an ID on two input-field, so I can grab it, then use it in a function. I can create the elements and then set an ID, but my task requires me to do it this way (School project).

```
var div = document.getElementById('div');
var p = document.createElement('p');

var butt = document.createElement('input');
var inputOne = document.createElement('input');
var inputTwo = document.createElement('input');


div.appendChild(inputOne);
div.appendChild(inputTwo);
inputOne.SetAttribute="type","text";
inputOne.placeholder="Something";
inputTwo.SetAttribute="type","number";
inputTwo.placeholder="SomethingElese";
butt.type="button";
butt.value="clickMe!";
div.appendChild(butt);
butt.onclick=func();
inputOne.SetAttribute="id","MyID";

function func(){
    var text = document.getElementById('MyID').value;
    alert(text);
}
```

Comment: do you have a element with `id="div"` if not, your `var div` will be `undefined`, everything else will not work. `setAttribute(name, value)` and not `SetAttribute` is a function. You need to study javascript syntax to make it work, you are mixing things there.

Comment: Yes I have. Ah ok, didn't realize, I'll give that a go.

Comment: A small and very good book to read and understand is Douglas Crockford Javascript The Good Parts, I don't agree with all of his statements in the book, but it's very small and will clarify to you how to use it in a very good way.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the errors.

```
var div = document.getElementById('div');
var p = document.createElement('p');

var butt = document.createElement('input'); // really? I can think of better names
var inputOne = document.createElement('input');
var inputTwo = document.createElement('input');


div.appendChild(inputOne);
div.appendChild(inputTwo);
inputOne.setAttribute("type","text"); // call this as a function with a lowercase "setAttribute"
inputOne.placeholder="Something";
inputTwo.setAttribute("type","number"); // this too
inputTwo.placeholder="SomethingElese";
butt.type="button";
butt.value="clickMe!";
div.appendChild(butt);
butt.onclick=func; // pass the function by reference, not calling it
inputOne.setAttribute("id","MyID"); // again
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working now. Here's the result code - Thanks!

```
var div = document.getElementById('myDiv');
var butt= document.createElement('input'); 
var inputOne = document.createElement('input');
var inputTwo = document.createElement('input');


div.appendChild(inputOne);
div.appendChild(inputTwo);
inputOne.setAttribute("type","text");
inputOne.placeholder="Something";
inputTwo.setAttribute("type","number");
inputTwo.placeholder="SomethingElse";
butt.type="button";
butt.value="ClickMe";
div.appendChild(butt);
butt.onclick=func;
inputOne.setAttribute("id","MyID");


function func(){
    var text = document.getElementById('MyID').value;
    alert(text);
}
```